# cloudfomationでdynamodbのhash+rengeの属性のテーブル作りたいがエラーが出る。

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

キースキーマをhash+rengeにしたい場合、どう書くのが正しいのでしょう？

---

#### 起こったエラー

```
1 validation error detected: Value 'RENGE' at 'keySchema.
2.member.keyType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [HASH, RANGE] (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2;
Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: L6GDTPVEFBAVKUOA4DR2LM9SHBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

#### 以下、dynamodbリソース作成コードのみ抜粋

```
"DynamoDBTable":{
    "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
    "Properties":{
        "TableName": {"Ref" : "DynamoDBTableName"},
        "BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
        "AttributeDefinitions":[
            {
                "AttributeName": "Id",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "Time",
                "AttributeType": "N"
            }
        ],
        "KeySchema":[
            {
                "AttributeName": "Id",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "Time",
                "KeyType": "RENGE"
            }
        ],
        "Tags":[
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": {"Ref" : "DynamoDBTableName"}
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: `RANGE` の綴りが誤っているかと。

Comment: うっかりでした。

Comment: 解決されたようならご自身で回答を投稿し、自己承認してください。

Answer (score 0):

綴りミスが原因で、RENGE ではなく RANGE でした。

```js
"DynamoDBTable":{
    "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
    "Properties":{
        "TableName": {"Ref" : "DynamoDBTableName"},
        "BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
        "AttributeDefinitions":[
            {
                "AttributeName": "Id",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "Time",
                "AttributeType": "N"
            }
        ],
        "KeySchema":[
            {
                "AttributeName": "Id",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "Time",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "Tags":[
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": {"Ref" : "DynamoDBTableName"}
            }
        ]
    }
},
```